# Can I save multiple command arguments for VS2012 debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

**Summary**: Is there an easy way to save alternate command arguments used by the Visual Studio debugger?

**Details**:

Visual Studio has an option to set `Command Argument` that are used by the debugger.  For example in the screenshot shown here I've set them to `FOO BAR`.  Sometimes when debugging a project I want to switch the arguments to test different input sets.  And often the arguments are much longer than just FOO BAR.  It would be nice if there was a way to save the arguments that I've typed and switch between them quickly.  Ideally it would also be possible to change the working directory at the same time.  But I haven't found a way to do this yet so that's why I'm asking here.  I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create new configuration(s) for this project. I see that your current active configuration is Debug (top left corner of project settings dialog). You can create new configuration(s), which will be based on this one, and name them like Debug-Test1, Debug-Test2, etc. After you will do this you will have a choice to switch between this configurations in VS Debug Toolbar.

Comment: Creating and running a new build configuration as this answer suggests creates a whole new build output tree. Workable but not ideal.